# neovim :PlugUpdate produces permission denied on all plugins

Tags: vim-plugin, neovim

When entering in vim and then running `:PlugUpdate` all the plugins can't be updated because of the error

```
 x <PLUGIN>:                                                                                        
      error: cannot open .git/FETCH_HEAD: Permission denied
```

I was able to upgrade VimPlugin with `:PlugUpgrade` without any issues.

I was able to update this before without any issues about a month ago, I found an article saying that I need to change the ownership of the directory with `chown` which I am assuming would need to be done at `$ sudo chown -R ~/.config/nvim/` but if I don't need to change owner then I'd prefer not to

Answer (score 1):

I was able to resolve it by changing ownership with `$ sudo chown -R $USER ~/.config/nvim/`

**note** make sure to `$ echo $USER` to make sure that it's the user you wish to change the ownership of the directory